# Нужна помощь с sql запросом (Среднее значение)

Tags: sql

Нужно вывести из таблицы максимальное среднее значение  возраста.
Вывод должен показывать пол и средний максимальный возраст, значние должно быть только одно.

Пробовал через несколько селектов и `union all`, средний максимальный возраст выводит, но появляются 2 значения(Мужчина макс и женщина макс) так как не могу сравнить мейл и фимейл.

Нужно только одно максимальное значение, а не максимальное для каждого пола не используя TOP/LIMIT:

```sql
select max (T.AvgAge) as Age, T.GENDER as gender 
from
(select avg(age) as AvgAge, GENDER
from Patient where gender = 'Male'
 group by GENDER
union all
select avg(age) as AvgAge, GENDER
from Patient where gender = 'Female'
 group by GENDER) as T
 group by T.GENDER
order by T.GENDER desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

В mysql так точно получится - взять первый результат в отсортированной таблице

```
select T.AvgAge as max, T.GENDER as gender 
from
  (
  select avg(age) as AvgAge, GENDER
    from Patient 
    where gender = 'Male'
  union all
  select avg(age) as AvgAge, GENDER
    from Patient 
    where gender = 'Female'
  ) as T
order by max desc 
limit 1
```

Comment: смысл группировки в подзапросах? `select avg, 'male' where gender = 'male'`, или какой нить `max(gender)`

Comment: да, точно, ща поправлю :)

Comment: Получается своего рода "хардкодинг" где используется 

MS Access Syntax:
SELECT TOP / 
MySQL Syntax:
LIMIT

Ищу способ сделать без этого

Comment: *Ищу способ сделать без этого* вы хотите решение для всех субд ?

Comment: Нет, подойдет для любой, там уже сам додумаю как адаптировать, главное что-бы небыло хардкодинга по топ/лимиту

Answer (score 0):

Можно вычислить оба сразу и выбрать больший:

```
select
  case when maleavgage > femaleavgage then 'Male'
       else 'Female' end as gender,
  case when maleavgage > femaleavgage then maleavgage
       else femaleavgage end as maxage
from (
  select
    avg(case gender when 'Male' then age end) as maleavgage,
    avg(case gender when 'Female' then age end) as femaleavgage
  from (
    select 'Вася' as name, 'Male' as gender, 42 as age union all
    select 'Петя', 'Male', 29 union all
    select 'Таня', 'Female', 23 union all
    select 'Изя', 'Male', 59 union all
    select 'Лена', 'Female', 29
  ) as Patient
) as T
```

**Результат:**

```
+--------+---------+
| gender | AvgAge  |
+--------+---------+
| Male   | 43,3333 |
+--------+---------+
```

[Демо](https://rextester.com/ZOVNI6832).